# socket.io game development algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, socket.io

Im trying to create a simple multiplayer game with letters and words on socket.io The algorith is below and mu question is. It is posible like i think to do?[image: algorith]

Comment: description: 1st user click on stop button and then both users in realtime get a letters and then they try to creating a bigger word, when they create a word, they send a word to a server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timer logic seems critical to the game play. It should be handled server side to avoid any trick from Player 2 who might forge an empty string request.

Comment: please tell e more specificly